# how to create panel with multiline title in flex 3 by extending mx.containers.Panel?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I need to make title of panel multiline, maybe someone have working example of subclass of Panel?
I have no success with overriding methods

some draft code: http://pastebin.com/7jXJqYNq

[image: result isn't satisfied me]

i've added border to titleTextField to find error, but it's not helped

Answer (score 0):

These guys had a discussion on that problem.
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Flex/Q_23477460.html

Although you may already have gotten that far.
Solution that they suggested was to override the createChildren() in 
the subclass and add a text component to the title. Let us know if it works sure.